# css not working properly in masterpages

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble setting up the href of my CSS.

My projected is located at

```
www.mysite.com/myproject/
```

My css is located at

```
www.mysite.com/myproject/styles/css/css.css
```

When I'm at `www.mysite.com/myproject/`, everything works fine. but when i go into a directory, `(www.mysite.com/myproject/dir1/)` the css is no longer found. My guess is that it's looking for the css at `www.mysite.com/myproject/dir1/styles/css/css.css`.

I'm currently using master pages. How do I properly reference the css?

**Edit**:
This is currently how i reference my CSS.

```
link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/content/css/bootmetro.css"
```

but it doesn't work properly because the project is not located at the root (www.mysite.com). it is located at `www.mysite.com/myproject/`. So having the "/" causes the css not to load at all.

Comment: Can you show us what you currently have in the masterpage?

Comment: You probably aren't using tilde in the path to your CSS file...

Comment: using absolute path in your web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the css path like this, starting slash means root of the site.

```
/styles/css/css.css
```

Comment: yes, but it's not really located at the root. i have it in mySite.abc/myProject/

Comment: is myProjec just a folder? or virtual application?

Comment: then it should be `/myProject/styles/css/css.css`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
 link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/css/bootmetro.css"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using ASP.NET, try like this:

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= ResolveURL("~/content/css/bootmetro.css")%>" />
```